# Xamarin Studio can't run Android application after update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Today I update Xamarin Studio, and like many times before, it's start crashing. The problem is that the Android application is installed but crash in lunch throwing the error:

`NotSupportedException: Stack walks are not supported on this platform.`

Did someone know how to fix it or what could be causing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug, which is raised on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55087). The only thing you can do right now is downgrade your Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Seems the issue is specific to Android version 7.3.x. as Chris Riesgo said in this [thread](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55087#c10). Thanks for help.

Comment: I will. But stackoverflow alert me that i need to wait 5 minutes because the question is recent!

Comment: Ah I was too fast ;)

Comment: It's done. My project work fine now. If some needs it. I downgrade as explained [here](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699777-how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-)